# Getting error in Log files for our XDBC server, please suggest what might be issue?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

```
10.200.30.400 - nuxeo [18/Jan/2017:12:48:10 +0000] "POST /eval XDBC/1.0" 200 101 - "Java/1.8.0_101 MarkLogicXCC/8.0-5"
10.200.30.400 - nuxeo [18/Jan/2017:12:48:10 +0000] "POST /eval XDBC/1.0" 200 0 - "Java/1.8.0_101 MarkLogicXCC/8.0-5"
10.200.30.400 - nuxeo [18/Jan/2017:12:48:10 +0000] "POST /eval XDBC/1.0" 200 0 - "Java/1.8.0_101 MarkLogicXCC/8.0-5"
10.200.30.400 - nuxeo [18/Jan/2017:12:48:10 +0000] "POST /eval XDBC/1.0" 200 0 - "Java/1.8.0_101 MarkLogicXCC/8.0-5"
10.200.30.400 - nuxeo [18/Jan/2017:12:48:10 +0000] "POST /eval XDBC/1.0" 200 0 - "Java/1.8.0_101 MarkLogicXCC/8.0-5"
```

Comment: What you've shown is the Access Log, and I see a bunch of 200s, which indicate successful calls. Where are you seeing an error?

Answer (score 2):

The access log (AccessLog.txt) for any XDBC or XCC capibile HTTP AppServer will show this.   XDBC is implemented using HTTP (a simplified form).  An 'ad-hoc' XDBC Eval uses the 'POST' method to the '/eval/ endpoint.  So as Dave says, your are seeing successful XDBC calls.

If using port 8000 or a REST port (ML Version 8+) you can do HTTP, REST and XDBC calls on the same port.  The result will be intermixed access logs from all clients.

'Its just HTTP'